# Java - Polar Coordinates. Given a line segment AB and a point P, find the closest point on the polar line AB to point P

Tags: java, android, polar-coordinates

I'm given a line segment with two endpoints: (x1,y1) (x2,y2) and a random point: (x3,y3).

If I convert the line segment to polar coordinates, I need to be able to figure out, programmatically, a point on the line segment that is the closest to point (x3,y3).

EDIT:
I made a mistake in my question.  The problem isn't trying to find the closest point between the three.  The problem is... given a line AB with a start and an end... find ANY point on the line that is closest to point (x3,y3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question involves elementary school level algebra:
There are only 3 options for the closest point:

- one of the points (x1,y1) (x2,y2)
- another point between them on the line segment

It's easy to find the distance between (x3,y3) to the two points using Pythagoras:

```
d1 = d(<x1,y1>,<x3,y3>) = sqrt( (x1-x3)^2 + (y1-y3)^2)
```

and

```
d2 = d(<x2,y2>,<x3,y3>) = sqrt( (x2-x3)^2 + (y2-y3)^2)
```

and now for the "more complicated" part: if there's another point on the segment which is closer to (x3,y3) - if we connect these points - we'll have a new segment that will be diagonal to the original segment - we have to use that together with a first degree equation (for a line) to find that third point and see if it's on the segment or outside (if it's outside of the segment then we'll take the minimum distance between (x3,y3) to the other two points.

The line equation (excuse my English - I learnt it in my native language so bear with me) is:

```
(I) y = mx + d
```

where m is easy to calculate:

```
m = (y1-y2)/(x1-x2)
```

and now that we know the value of `m` in order to find `d` we'll use the values of one of the first two points, for example:

```
y1 = mx1 +d  =>   d = y1 - mx1
```

the diagonal line will have `m'` which is `-1/m` and if we'll use the values of (x3,y3) we'll find `d'`. So now we know both the values of (I) as well as the equation for the diagonal line:

```
(II) y=m'x + d'
```

and if we'll use these two equations we can find the point on the line through which the original segment goes through which is the closest to (x3,y3) - if this point lies on the segment - we're done, otherwise, like earlier mentioned - we'll take the minimum between  `d1` and `d2`

Comment: @SmartLemon then convert the polar coordinates to Cartesian :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  You pretty much confirmed what I knew... I guess my code is spewing out incorrect coordinates.  I just wanted to make sure that I'm not going crazy.  It just looks like there's a bug somewhere else in my code.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is too late, just in case someone needs it, I just convert back to cartesian coordinates so the formula is easier to look at:

```
 public static double distance(double r1,double t1,double r2,double t2,double r3,double t3)
 {
   double x1 = (r1*Math.cos(t1));
   double x2 = (r1*Math.cos(t2));
   double x3 = (r1*Math.cos(t3));
   double y1 = (r1*Math.sin(t1));
   double y2 = (r1*Math.sin(t2));
   double y3 = (r1*Math.sin(t3));

   return Math.abs((x2-x1)*(y1-y3)-(x1-x3)*(y2-y1))/Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Location closest(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3){
    Location a = new Location("provider");
    Location b = new Location("provider");
    Location c = new Location("provider");

    //I can't remember which one goes where, you may need to swap all the x/ys around
    //Do conversion or something here. 

    a.setLongitude(x1);
    a.setLatitude(y1);

    b.setLongitude(x2);
    b.setLatitude(y2);

    c.setLongitude(x3);
    c.setLongitude(y3);

    return closest(a, b, c);
}

public static Location closest(Location a, Location b, Location c){
    return a.distanceTo(c) < b.distanceTo(c) ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but this only solves for the closest between the three points.  What I'm looking for is trying to find ANY point on the line that is closest to point x3,y3.

Comment: Ohhh I see what you want. Sorry xD. I have some stuff for this somwhere.

Comment: No problem.  Looks like alfasin figured it out.  I already had his solution, but I guess there's an error somewhere else in my code that is pumping out the wrong numbers!  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't going crazy.

Comment: What you need to do is find the parallel line that the third point makes with the line segment, then find how far along that line it is, then make a triangle between one of the points at the end of the line segment, then get the point in which there is a 90 degree angle, that is the nearest point on the line to the third point.

Comment: Actually, you dont need the parallel line, you just need to somehow find the distance it is parallel to the other line